# Need help parsing combined forms of a verb

Tags: translation, verbs, passive-voice

I came across this verb:

> 捕【と】らえられていた

It could have been pretty much any verb really. I tried to parse the different forms the verb has been assigned. Here's my process:

捕【と】らえる - (Transitive verb) **To catch**

捕【と】らえられる - (Passive form) - **To get caught**

捕【と】らえられていた　- (Passive, past-progressive form) - **Had been getting caught**

**Question**: I want to know if my understanding of these forms (combined) is correct or not.

In other words, 捕【と】らえられていた = **Had been getting** caught?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am afraid that your understanding of the third form is incorrect.

「捕らえられていた」 is the equivalent of the English "**pluperfect** passive voice".  There is no "progressive" expressed in this.

In English, it would be "had been caught (and had stayed in captivity since)".